# What keys can I put in a podfile?

Tags: cocoapods

I can't seem to find a reference for what exactly is available in a Podfile. For instance, this is an example given to make Swift modules play nicely with Pods:

```
post_install do |installer|
     installer.pods_project.build_configuration_list.build_configurations.each do |configuration|
         configuration.build_settings['CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES'] = 'YES'
     end
end
```

But is there something else in `installer` besides `pod_project`? Is there something else in `configuration` besides `build_settings`? [The docs](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html) don't say anything about it, and neither does a web search. Is there a reference or guide out there somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned the [docs](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#post_install) specify that  `Pod::Installer` is the only input for the post-install hook and it has an [API](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/cocoapods/cocoapods/Pod/Installer) you can look at for whatever it exposes.